# ng-repeat with getting array from php

Tags: php, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok, so this seems simple enough but evidently i'm missing something, and i've given up trying to understand what, my code goes something like this:

on my php side I read info from MySql database and it returns a json encoded object as such:

```
$rows = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $rows[]=$row;
        }    

        echo json_encode($rows);
```

on to my Angular javascript side, I attempt to load the contents of this array into an array i have created in the scope of one of my controllers (i have 2)

```
$scope.CurrentOIDs=[];
            $scope.populate = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'getOidJSON.php',
                    data: {criteria: '', archived: 'NO'},
                    success: function (phpmarkup) {
                        $scope.CurrentOIDs = JSON.parse(phpmarkup);   
                        console.log($scope.CurrentOIDs);
                    }
                });
            };
```

!when checking the console, the information shows up perfect, i get an array of 50 elements and all the info is there exactly how i need it as can be seen in the image here -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy4hW.png)

i try to put all my data in a table using the following html,

```
 <div id="quicksearchresults" ng-controller="EditableRowCtrl" data-ng-init="populate()">
    <div id='searchResults'>
        <table id='resultstable'>
            <thead>
               <tr style='background-color:#333333; color:whitesmoke;' class='headers'>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='OIDid'>OID#</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='priority'>Priority</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='topic'>Topic</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='category'>Category</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='task'>Task</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='added'>Added</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='target'>Target</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='owner'>Owner</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='remarks'>Remarks</th>
                      <th style='white-space: nowrap;' class='sort' data-sort='status'>Status</th>
               </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody class='list'>
                <tr ng-repeat='task in CurrentOIDs'>
                    <td class='OIDid'>{{ task.OIDid }}</td>
                    <td class='priority'>{{ task.Priority }}</td>
                    <td class='topic'>{{ task.Topic }}</td>
                    <td class='category'>{{ task.Category }}</td>
                    <td class='task'>{{ task.Task }}</td>      
                    <td class='added'>{{ task.Added }}</td>
                    <td class='target'>{{ task.Target }}</td>
                    <td class='owner'>{{ task.Owner }}</td>
                    <td class='remarks'>{{ task.Remarks }}</td>
                    <td class='status' style='font-size:150%; font-weight:bold;'>{{ task.Status }}%</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </div>
</div>
```

now i know this works when i manually give the same exact values to the array in my javascript instead of reading them from the database. the one difference i did note, is that each object has a field added to it $$hashkey, but as far as i can understand this is added because of the ng-repeat.

My knowledge of angular is still basic, and i have no idea why this is not working, and have run out of stuff to search on google for it. ANY and ALL help is greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Can you paste the complete controller code ?

Comment: You're using jQuery to make the AJAX call, and its success callback happens outside of Angular's digest loop. Use `$scope.$apply()`, or (preferably) use `$http` to make the AJAX call.

Comment: ok so ironically enough, seconds after posting this question I tried $scope.$apply() and it worked, i don't fully understand what is happening though, can you explain more why i needed this command here? thanks

Comment: $http is angular specific and returns a promise, AJAX-Call of jQuery isn't "builtin" in angularJS.

If the AJAX-Call comes back, angularJS, doesn't realize that you changed data, if you use $http, angularJS knows theres something ongoing and makes a dirty check over your data and binds them.
Further information: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596744/why-use-http-in-angular-instead-of-jquerys-ajax)

Comment: ok so i'm trying to implement this using $http and i got to this: $http.get('getOidJSON.php',{criteria: '', archived: 'NO'})
                        .success( function (phpmarkup) {
                            $scope.CurrentOIDs = phpmarkup; 
                            console.log($scope.CurrentOIDs);
                        }); no surprises here though, it's not working, the error this time on php side, the data doesn't seem to be getting there, any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use $http.post and grab data on php side like: 
`$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postData);`